# Angular JS an alternative to traditional jQuery AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, single-page-application

I used AJAX a lot.Its good not to reload a page ,just a part of page without even knowing to user.
I saw lots of sites using Angular JS and what i found common in them is :

```
1.All use AJAX stuff which is angular js based.

2.Most of the website didnt use reload method to open pages , it smoothly jumps from page 1 to 2.
```

My question is : Is Angular JS an alternative to traditional jQuery AJAX call & page navigation without reload ?

I didnt find this question answered anywhere.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not really an alternative but a framework. Angular uses ajax like functionality and indeed contains a light jquery implementation within itself. It is a whole lot more though as its a MVC framework and amongst others some notable features are two way data binding, directives (adding features if you will to html) etc

Answer (score 0):

No It is not. Actually, AngularJs is a framework suits for single page applications ans MVC design pattern and tries to include everything it needs in itself without using any other libraries. Along with AngularJs you can use other libraries such as jquery but in order to keep your codes clear and being maintained easily later, it's a good practice to work with angularjs functions.

Comment: It is *not* just for single page apps, you make it sound like it is. We're using it very well to replace just some specific parts of a website with Angular. For example our comment system is a directive I can simply throw on any page and get comments. It is a very good framework to resolve the unstructured JS and especially jQuery mess where 1/3 or 1/2 of the code feels like it's made only of selectors.